# Why is this request cancel not working in axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, request, axios

I am trying to cancel the request when the input in my search field is empty so the results don't show after the input is deleted.

I tried not to use cancel request and it works, the only problem is that I delete characters too fast the results don't dissapear.
Declared this outside component:

```
const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
```

Also tried declaring it inside the handler same result.

This is the state :

```
state = {
        results: null
    }
```

And the function triggered on change

```
findGames = (event) => { //Cancel request when empty event.target.value missing
        let searchText = event.target.value;
        source.cancel('Request Canceled');
        if (event.target.value !== "") {
            let body = {
                "search_text": `${searchText}`, "fields": ["id", "name", "release_dates"]
            }

            axios.post(getGameIDUrl, body, headers,{cancelToken: source.token})
                .then(res => res.data.filter((result) => { return result.type === "game" }))
                .then(res => this.setState({ results: res }))
                .catch(err => {
                    if(axios.isCancel(err)) {
                        console.log('Request Canceled')
                    }
                })
        } else {
            this.setState({results: null})
        }

    }
```

This is how I trigger the function:

```
<StyledInput type="text" onChange={this.findGames} />
```

Then I just display the results:

```
{this.state.results}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason `axios.CancelToken.source();` is unique each time you press a key. So for your code: request you've sent will never be cancelled and you try to cancel request that you've not sent.

You have to preserve `axios.CancelToken.source();` between calls and to me it also makes sense to cancel request unconditionally you've sent on previous keystroke.

That not only covers case with empty string but also saves us from race conditions when responses for sequential keystrokes return in wrong order.

```
// source is declared outside event handler to be preserved between calls
this.source.cancel('Request Canceled');
this.source = axios.CancelToken.source();
if (event.target.value) {
    let body = {
        "search_text": `${searchText}`, 
        "fields": ["id", "name", "release_dates"]
    }
    axios.post(getGameIDUrl, body, headers,{cancelToken: this.source.token})
        .then(res => res.data.filter((result) => { return result.type === "game" }))
        .then(res => this.setState({ results: res }))
        .catch(err => {
            if(axios.isCancel(err)) {
                console.log('Request Canceled')
            }
        }) 
} else {
  this.setState({ results: [] });
}
```

Comment: I tried but didn't work. Can it be because I set the results of the previous request to the state? I do set the state back to null when the input field is empty but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: not sure if I follow. where do you set up state to `null`? what do you mean `previous request` in current context?

Comment: I updated the question to make show how I trigger the request.

Comment: btw, in my snippet I missed clearing results for empty string. is that what you asked?

Comment: I tried as you said but same results even with the source decalred outside. I updated the question again.

Answer (score 2):

If your responseType is "stream" then cancelling with CancelToken or the new AbortController won't work. You have to close the stream.

With the console.log in response.data.on you can see that the log will stop, after calling response.data.destroy.

```
var options = {
      url: url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: {credentials: "something"},
      responseType: "stream"
}
const response = await axios(options)
setTimeout(() => {
    response.data.destroy()//--> this will close the stream and the download will stop
}, 3000);
response.data.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log("chunk length: ", chunk.length)
})
```

What I did is create a variable outside my request function, so that I can stop the request by changing the variable.

```
var cancelDownload = false
function requestFun() {
    var options = {
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: { credentials: "something" },
        responseType: "stream"
    }
    const response = await axios(options)
    response.data.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log("chunk length: ", chunk.length)
        if (cancelDownload) {
            response.data.destroy()
            cancelDownload = false
        }
    })
}
```

PS: Even though this post is pretty old I wanted to give my solution.